# Duplicate class error in gRPC dependencies when running the app

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, grpc, proto

I was beginning to try **gRPC** on android and added all the dependencies.
When I want to run the project I get the following error. It's my first time implementing **gRPC** in android and it's starting to get annoying right from the start.

```
Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite$Builder$LimitedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.AbstractProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.BooleanArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteBufferWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteOutput found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ArraysByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$BoundedByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$ByteIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$CodedBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LeafByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ByteString$SystemByteArrayCopier found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$AbstractBufferedEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ArrayEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$ByteOutputEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutOfSpaceException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.DoubleArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExperimentalApi found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryFactory found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.ExtensionRegistryLite$ObjectIntPair found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FieldSet$FieldDescriptorLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.FloatArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$DefaultInstanceBasedParser found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessage$ExtensionWriter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtendableMessageOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$ExtensionDescriptor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$GeneratedExtension found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$MethodToInvoke found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.IntArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$BooleanList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$DoubleList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$EnumLiteMap found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$FloatList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$IntList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ListAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$LongList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$Converter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$EntryAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$IteratorAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$MapAdapter$SetAdapter found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Internal$ProtobufList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyEntry found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyField$LazyIterator found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyFieldLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteArrayListView found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList$ByteStringListView found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LazyStringList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.LongArrayList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapEntryLite$Metadata found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MapFieldLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLite$Builder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteOrBuilder found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.MessageLiteToString found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.TextFormatEscaper$ByteSequence found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UninitializedMessageException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSetLite found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnmodifiableLazyStringList$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeByteOperations found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$Processor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$SafeProcessor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnpairedSurrogateException found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnsafeProcessor found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$3 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$FieldType$4 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$JavaType found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$1 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$2 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    Duplicate class com.google.protobuf.WireFormat$Utf8Validation$3 found in modules protobuf-javalite-3.17.2 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2) and protobuf-lite-3.0.1 (com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1)
    
    Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

**Here is my `build.gradle` file (app level):**

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.16'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "it.tdaapp.grpcexample"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.2"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.39.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all().each { task ->
            task.builtins {
                java { option 'lite' }
            }
            task.plugins {
                grpc { option 'lite' }
            }
        }
    }
}


dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'

    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:1.39.0' 
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:1.39.0' 
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.39.0' 
    implementation 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Please help me, I've been stuck on this for hours!!
**Thanks**

Comment: Your problem is with the protobuf-lite & transitive grpc-protobuf-lite dependencies, you're bringing in both old style protobuf-lite & new stye protobuf-javalite, you can google it to understand what's behind this. Personally, for a smaller grpc project on Android that does not necessarily need protobuf, I'd use Kotlin with grpc-kotlin and plug in Kotlin serialization instead of protobuf, to eclipse protobuf-lite messes. That's a slightly advanced use case, though; there is a grpc blog post about replacing the protobuf piece with grpc-java and you can do the equivalent thing with grpc-kotlin.

Comment: For the time being you'll be better off fixing those lite artifact clashes I think. Just start out with  android samples on the grpc website/github.

Comment: @Uli Thanks for the comment. I did what you said and implemented the samples from the grpc website and now it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The `protobuf-lite` package was a short-lived name. Protobuf only released two versions of it (3.0.0 and 3.0.1) before renaming it to `protobuf-javalite`.

You are depending on the old name: `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-lite:3.0.1`. Replace that dependency with `com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.17.2` to match the protoc version.